# Check Username Availability Error

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2007

I got this error when i wanna try to check availability username that is have in database or not, the error says: "Input string was not in correct format".

Here is the code:

```
private void CheckUsername()
{
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\Archives\Projects\Program\Sell System\Sell System\App_Data\db1.accdb";

conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT [Username] FROM [Member], conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("Username", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["Username"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;

int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

if (count != 0)
{
System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
sound.Play();
MessageBox.Show("Username already exists! Please use another username", "Warning");
}

else
{
System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
sound.Play();
MessageBox.Show("Username is not exists!", "Congratulations");
}
}
```

The error pointed in: `int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` and the error says: "input string was not in correct format"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please start using parameterized queries. This approach is a sql injection disaster waiting to happen

Comment: Is the username an integer?

Comment: @TGH: Thanks, i will do it!

Comment: @user814064: not, the username is a string

Comment: Then why are you trying to convert the username to an integer?

Comment: Solved! instead of doing "executeScalar....", i use executeReader!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first I'd like to give you a tip on using parameters in your queries, second, I think you meant to write `COUNT()` in your SQL:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT([Username]) FROM [Member] WHERE [Username] = ?", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(textBox1.Text);
```